# Display all the processes with top

Tags: command-line

I tried to view all the processes dynamically with command `top`,
unfortunately, it not allows forward movements of command `less`, just show one page.

Meanwhile, `top` command works properly on ubuntu.

How to solve the problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you're looking for. Please provide better detail. A majority of CLI commands such as `less`, `bash` itself, and many others are not updated and need to be updated through homebrew or by yourself. UPDATE: I also recommend `htop` over `top`.